# Regex wiping file

Tags: java, regex

I have written a method in Java to delete a caret at the end of each line of a file. The method is as follows:

```
//Creates a new file, and deletes the temp file
  public void createFinalFile() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    // read file data into a String
    String data1 = new Scanner(new File(fileDirectoryString + "tempFile.txt")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
    // replace all ^ from end of line using (?m) - MULTILINE switch
    data1 = data1.replaceAll("(?m)\\^$", "");
    PrintWriter docketFile3 = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(fileDirectoryString + "Forclosure-Docket-"+startingYear+startingMonth+startingDay+"-"+endingYear+endingMonth+endingDay+".txt", true));
    docketFile3.write(data1);
  }
```

The issue is that sometimes the temp file will have all the information, but after the method is run the newly created file is blank and I am not sure why. An example of the temp file is:

```
04/02/2014^BR-12-005193^09/12/2012^P1^SF^DEPOSIT AMOUNT PAID CUYAHOGA COUNTY SHERIFF^
04/02/2014^BR-12-005193^09/12/2012^P1^CS^COST PAYMENT  $860.90 CUYAHOGA COUNTY SHERIFF^
```

While it should just delete the caret at the end of each line, it seems to be deleting every line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regular expression is not what's doing this. Though the function overall reminds me more of [this](http://xkcd.com/763/) than anything else, it should work. The one thing though that could be going wrong is that you aren't closing your output file. Add `docketFile3.close();` as a line after you write the data out.

Comment: Awesome, that seems to have fixed it. Interesting that it would work on occasion.